# only web application should access and write data in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, security

I have a java web application with a Mysql relational database. I would like that only the web application could access, write and delete data in the database and prevent direct changes to database even by the administrator of the database.
Is it possible?

Comment: If a user has database administration rights, they can administer the database. You need to revoke that privilege.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to stop Database administrator to access a database in MySQL. As I know, only Oracle Database Vault can do that.